# In woocommerce product details not showing

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm new in wordpress and woocommerce development part. I'm trying to integrate woocommerce for my products, everything was fine. But when i click on product permalink for product details or product single page it's redirect to the same page. Interesting thing is when i click on product, the url changed but not go through to the details page.

Here is the page link- https://dev.shopvitalsleep.com/collections/all/

I'm using loop inside woocommerce.php with my custom designed page.

Here is the code sample-

```php
<div class="row justify-content-center equal-box">
    <?php
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => 12
            );
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
            if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
                while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
                    $product = wc_get_product($loop->post->ID);

                    ?>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 mb-4">
                        <div class="product-content text-center">
                            <div class="product-images">
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="product-details-link">
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="product-info">
                              <h4 class="product-title"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h4>                     
                              <div class="price">
                                            
                              <p>
                                <span class="reg-price">
                                    <del>$<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_regular_price', true ); ?></del>
                                </span>
                                <span class="sell-price">now $<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_sale_price', true ); ?> USD</span>
                              </p>                              
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        <div class="row mt-auto product-content text-center mb-2">
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <a class="button style-blue view-detail-button" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">View Details</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <div class="add-to-cart "><?php
                                        echo sprintf( '<a href="%s" data-quantity="1" class="%s" %s>%s</a>',
                                            esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
                                            esc_attr( implode( ' ', array_filter( array(
                                                'button', 'product_type_' . $product->get_type(),
                                                $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() ? 'add_to_cart_button' : '',
                                                $product->supports( 'ajax_add_to_cart' ) ? 'ajax_add_to_cart' : '',
                                            ) ) ) ),
                                            wc_implode_html_attributes( array(
                                                'data-product_id'  => $product->get_id(),
                                                'data-product_sku' => $product->get_sku(),
                                                'aria-label'       => $product->add_to_cart_description(),
                                                'rel'              => 'nofollow',
                                            ) ),
                                            esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
                                        );
                                      ?>
                               </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php                           
                        endwhile;
                    } else {
                        echo __( 'No products found' );
                    }
                    wp_reset_postdata();
                ?>
            </div>
```

Folder structure:
`../themes/theme-name/woocommerce.php`

Please help me to findout where i make mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your WooCommerce single page is not working.
Take a look at their official docs for the correct file structure. I think you have a problem here referencing incorrect file or you have overwritten core file, like woocommerce.php.

You should use a child theme and then do your edits there.

[WooCommerce Docs Template Structure](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!
The problem is `woocommerce.php` file. This file overwrite the other directory.
In my case, I'm developing a custom theme that's why I need to create a directory inside my `../themes/my-theme` nameed- `/woocommerce/archive-product.php` and delete `woocommerce.php` form `../themes/my-theme`

So, moral of the topic is-
If your theme has a `woocommerce.php` file, you will be unable to override the `woocommerce/archive-product.php` custom template in your theme, as `woocommerce.php` has priority over other template files. This is intended to prevent display issues.